# How to inflate a ListView into a LinearLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I have created a `ListView` by using `ArrayAdapter` where a list of items are included.  I want to add this `ListView` into another `LinearLayout` where if anyone click it will show the list of items. Can that be achieved?. Please anyone help me.

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem somehow? Or you're here for a working solution?

Comment: Please show us some code...

Comment: I tried this but I did not able to come up with a solution. For your clearance I created a list view like the link http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429. And my problem is I want to inflate this list of items over a linearlayout. Did you got my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an OnClickListener to your LinearLayout and then just out this in your Listener :

```
LinearLayout lr = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLinearlayout);
lr.addView(Listview);
```

Comment: Your solution is not works. Actually I want to inflate the listview item on linearlayout.

Comment: Actually after doing lots of research at last I got the answer. I created a ListView and I want to show it as a inflatedview when I clicked a button. To do this just I add a line in menifest file which is used to show the list as a dialog. Here is the line 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

Thanks all for helping me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you only have to create a TextView from the text of your Iten and then add it to your LinearLayout :

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // String define above
    strText = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    LinearLayout lr = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLinearlayout);
    //Create a textview 
    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    //Set the text of the TextView with the Item Text
    tv.setText(strText);
    //Add it to your ListView
    lr.addView(Listview);


}
```